# More efficient continuous integration tool for PHP

Tags: php, jenkins, continuous-integration

I'm formerly a java developer but for a specific need I have to include CI for some PHP modules.

my question : what's the simplest way/tool to use for CI for PHP modules ?

thank's in advance.

Comment: What do you mean for modules? Are you developing these moduls? Are you talking about PHP extensions (PECL) or PHP libraries written in PHP code? And why is CI with PHP different to CI with Java?

Comment: I think most PHP guys would say Jenkins, http://jenkins-ci.org/

Comment: yes , some libraries written in PHP received from an external developers. I don't think there's a difference between PHP/JAVA CI as CI doesn't depend on language (it's just a kind of super scheduler), I just need advises as I'm not a PHP developer and may be I'm missing something. Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've always used Jenkins + ANT as a solution for our PHP sites. There is no (mature) CI server aimed specifically at PHP as far as I know. As an addition/alternative to 'classic' ant you can use [Phing](http://www.phing.info/).

See the buildfile of CakePHP (my favorite php framework) https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/build.xml for some inspiration.